# How Can I change bootstrap-modal width in my situation?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use the below way to load modal content to main html:

main html:

```
<div class="modal modal-custom fade" id="custom-view">
</div>
.....
```

modal html(on a Individual html):

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content message_align">
        <div class="modal-body" align="center">
            <span class="section">Custom Info</span>
                {% crispy form form.helper%}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I load the modal content to main html like this:

```
$(".mod-custom").click(function(ev) {
    ......
    $("#custom-view").load(url, function() {
        $("#custom-view").modal('show');
    }
}
```

the url is to render data on modal html

In my situation,How to change the width?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this link might help. Changing modal size.
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/bootstrap/modal.php#myModal2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the modal-content width, you can add modal-content width when #custom-view on click

```
$(".mod-custom").click(function(ev) {
......
$("#custom-view").load(url, function() {
    $("#custom-view").modal('show');
$('.modal-content').css({'width':'900px'});
}}
```

just change the class `.modal-content` if you want to change another class